# Accessing iPhone and android phonebook in as3

Tags: android, iphone, actionscript-3, flash-cs5.5

I want to fetch all contacts in iPhone and android phonebook in my application in AS3. How can this be done in as3?

-Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You're going to need to use a Native Extension.

Check this one out:

https://github.com/memeller/ContactEditor

Comment: I am getting this error while deploying ipa.. 
"An implementation for native extension 'pl.mllr.extensions.contactEditor' required by the application was not found for the target platform." please help me out..

Answer (score 0):

For iPhone, first you have to add Addressbook and AddressbookUI framework.

Then, for fetching contacts, you have to implement following methods...

```
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier
```

then,, `- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person`

and at last `- (void)peoplePickerNavigationControllerDidCancel:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker`

Now, set `return NO`
in **Second** method, call one method....like

```
[self displayContact:person];
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
return NO;
```

and in Third view, set this..`[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

Now, for that method...

```
-(void)displayContact:(ABRecordRef)person
{

name = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
lblname.text = name;

ABMultiValueRef phNumbers = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);

if(ABMultiValueGetCount(phNumbers) > 0)
{
    //NSLog(@"Count is:%ld",ABMultiValueGetCount(phNumbers));
    phone = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phNumbers, 0);
    btnsms.hidden = NO;
    btnedit.hidden = NO;
}
else
{
    phone = @"[NONE]";
}

lblphno.text = phone;

}
```

By implementing this, you can see name and phone no.in your labels....:)